# xcode (osx) : clic on button in view of custom view controller failed

Tags: nsviewcontroller

OSX 10.7.5 - XCode 4.6.1 - application OSX, not iOS.
Code very simple.
A `Window > contentWiew > subView with ViewController > Button`. The button is created using `ViewController.xib`.

All displays as expected, but when I click on the button, all fails. All Objects are not `nil`.

```
ViewController *viewController = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil];
NSView *aView = [NSView new];
aView = [viewController view];
[[_window contentView] addSubview:aView];
```

In Console :

```
[NSContentSizeLayoutConstraint buttonAct:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1061178a0
```

Answer (score 0):

You create a view controller which has a view associated with it.  You create a new NSView.  You overwrite your newly created NSView with the view controller's view.  Finally, you add a reference to the view controller's view to the window's content view.

```
//this does the same as your above code
ViewController *viewController = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil];
//in ios, you typically don't add things straight to the window
[[_window contentView] addSubview:viewController.view];
```

This is saything that buttonAct: isn't class method for NSContentSizeLayoutConstraint.

```
[NSContentSizeLayoutConstraint buttonAct:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1061178a0
```